# PNG image not transparent on website, cannot find out why

Tags: html, css, png, transparency

I am working on a dutch site and i am having a problem with the logo of it.
I saved the logo as PNG24 sothat the characters "hvb" in the logo will be transparent.
for some odd reason, it shows the characters in plain old white.

Could somebody please tell me how this is possible.
By the way: it is not caused by the h1 tag it is wrapped around.

http://www.luukratief-design.nl/wp/

Help would be appreciated

***EDIT:***

I have never seen this befor, but you guys where right! The image HAS indeed have white letters!
The odd part about it is that the layers were hidden, so they look transparent in photoshop. Once i used save for web and exported it to png, all of a sudden they are white. Take a look at the screeny:

[image]

**The solution:**
As stupid as it sounds, i deleted the white layers (which werent even visible), and exported it again. As you can see it works now.

I can only choose 1 right answer, so i will choose the first guy who pointed this out. Thanks guys. Still strange, but thanks!

Comment: This confuses me. The letters are white, but you want them transparent? The file is a legit transparent png, what is the issue?
`I saved the logo as PNG24 sothat the characters "hvb" in the logo will be transparent` - is that really what you mean?

Comment: I had the very same problem, and strangely enough Luuk's embedded answer solved it, i.e. deleting the *hidden* layers (that were not transparent but covered the same area that was supposed to be transparent) solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The letters are white in the image file.

Comment: He said he wants them transparent.

Comment: This is the only explanation. You need to have another look at the image, the letters ARE white. They are not, nor have ever been, transparent by the looks of things.

Comment: @Madmartigan — He said they **were** transparent but something was preventing the background from shining through. That something is that they **aren't** really transparent.

Comment: +1 - I'm with David. @Madmartigan - Well he'd best draw them transparent in his image file then.

Comment: Ah I stand corrected, it was me who misunderstood. I always forget to assume the obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The logo appears to have transparency for me. I am using Chrome.

Also transparency with PNGs does not work in IE6 or older without some javascript fiddling.
See: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Comment: His file does have transparency though.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the rest of the image is transparent.

Comment: PNG24 is PNG32. Although it is 32 bit for some reason the name PNG24 was used. Probably an older version that was only 24 bit. However, all PNG's support transparency, it's just that PNG8 doesn't support *alpha* transparency

Answer (score 1):

I made the simple change for you and made the letters transparent. You can use it all you like. No charge! ;)

[image]

EDIT: Obviously you can do a much better job if you take a bit of time, but editing in image editing software is the only way for them to be transparent.

Seeing as the "h" of hvb has a nice flick at the end, surely its not meant to be transparent?!

Answer (score 0):

When I change background to black, letters are white. There is no problem with implementation to site, I think problem is in image file.

I had difficulty with comprehension questions, second option:

Also if you using IE, and you have problems with transparent image corners and edges, use js code to fix it.

And if you want that letters be transparent, u need to edit image file with Adobe Ilustrator, or Photoshop or with somethnig else, what you using.

Link: [IE Transparency](http://spirit.vn/en/?p=37)